# Need to change display resolution on Windows Server 2019 Standart

Tags: resolution, display-driver, windows-server-2019

I need to change resolution on my server with default microsoft driver. Is it possible? I've installed nvidia G210 videocard, but when i install a driver "342.01-desktop-win10-64bit" computer is stuck randomly. Now there is no way to change graphic card. Server run good when i uninstall nvidia driver and disable driver automatic install for this card. But resolution is 800x600. Is it possbile to change it to 1600x900?

Comment: Your not going to be able to achieve what you want with the basic display driver. There is a good chance Nvidia doesn’t support your card on Windows Server 2019 due to its age.

Comment: Did you try letting Windows Update find and install a driver? Also, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Yes i'm tried to update driver via windows update and no luck. Driver "342.01-desktop-win10-64bit" work correctly until i'm use some soft "BAS" which use GPU HW acceleration and it's can't be turned off. When i'm use default driver it's work fine withouth any HW acceleration.

Comment: Nvidia driver selection says that this driver is the one to use. What is soft "BAS"? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc BAS is a browser automation studio. It use gpu hw acceleration and it can't be disabled. I'm tried to disable it via windows display graphic settings but tab "troubleshoot" isnt exist

Comment: I don't know BAS and can't help with it. You might try to get in touch with the developers, or just uninstall it and find a replacement.